# Salutations informelles dans un courriel

Tags: politesse, formulation, langage-informel

Ma question sera la suivante : dans un courriel, on écrit amicalement « À bientôt »  ou « Cordialement », mais y a t-il d'autres formules de politesse pour finir une lettre ?

Il s'agit d'une communication en masse parmi des personnes de même statut social, lesquelles se connaissent plus ou moins les unes les autres.

Les dites formules de politesse amicales sont-elles fixées, ou peut-on les combiner pour éviter des répétitions ennuyeuses ?

Answer (score 3):

*cordialement* est sans doute l'une des formules de politesses informelle les plus utilisées. Du même type, il est possible d'utiliser *chaleureusement*, qui est similaire (même sens), mais qui est plus original.

J'utilise fréquemment "*bien à vous*", qui est tout à fait correct et qui correspond à "*je reste à votre disposition si besoin*".

"*Vous souhaitant une agréable après-midi / journée / semaine*" (en fonction du moment de la journée et la fréquence de vos échanges) est également courant et facilement personnalisable.

Il est également possible de les combiner :

> Vous souhaitant une agréable après-midi,
>
> Cordialement, Mistalis

> Dans l'attente de vos nouvelles,
>
> Chaleureusement, Mistalis

Comment: "Cordialement" reste très formel.

Answer (score 1):

Très familier et d'un usage restreint (proches, jeunes générations), on trouve aussi parfois:

> A+

abréviation de *à plus tard*. Mais je ne le recommande pas dans votre contexte, je le cite simplement pour référence.